# cURL in powershell doesn't work

Tags: powershell, curl, command-line

I have some JSON and I am trying to use with curl.

```
$json = [char]93 + "{"fields":{"project":{"key":"TEST"},"summary":"Test of the REST","description":"Issue created using the REST API","issuetype":{"name":"Bug"}}}` + [char]93
```

I've used `[char]39` because I can't use the `'` character in variable.

I'm trying to post this JSON using JIRA Rest API and PowerShell.
I've checked that format of the JSON and the cURL is ok (tested on Linux host).
Unfortunately the following command doesn't work for me.

```
curl https://jira.internal/rest/api/2/issue/ -f -u user:p@ssw0rd! -H "Content-type:application/json" -X POST -d $json
```

Comment: 'Doesn't work' tells us very little. What error do you get?

Comment: Hi Jeremiah,I got 400 Bad request it's very very strange becouse when I do this same operation on linux host everything works like a charm. I think that it can be problem with encoding becouse when I export this JSON to file with UTF-8 encoding and grab this file into cURL it's works. But I don't know how to set encoding on powershell variable to check it I search a lot, but don't find solution.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in PowerShell 4.0 in Windows and solved it via 
linebrackets and "@"symbols. Try following:

```
$json= @'
{
   "fields":{
       "project":{"key":"TEST"}
   },
   "summary":"Test of the REST",
   "description":"Issue created using the REST API",
   "issuetype":{
        "name":"Bug"
   }  
}
'@
```